# Listing negative numbers in zenity --list

Tags: options, zenity

```
$ zenity --list --column 'Numbers' '-3'
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

$ zenity --list --column 'Numbers' -- '-3'
```

[image: list of ['--', '-3']]

So obviously zenity is interpreting the '-' in '-3' as the beginning of an option. How do I prevent it?

---

Currently, I'm working around it with `' -3'` but is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your system has UTF-8 support, you could display negative numbers using [unicode minus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm):

```
zenity --list --column 'Numbers' −3
zenity --list --column 'Numbers' $'\xE2\x88\x923'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply entries via the standard input:

```
echo -3 | zenity --list --column 'Numbers'
```

Each entry is separated by a new line. So if you want to supply multiple entries you will need to do something like one of these options:

```
(echo -1; echo -2; echo -3) | zenity --list --column 'Numbers'

echo -e '-1\n-2\n-3' | zenity --list --column 'Numbers'

echo -1 -2 -3 | tr ' ' '\n' | zenity --list --column 'Numbers'
```